# JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm using jedis for simple key-value data store... My code is as follows

```
private static final String HOST = "50.30.35.9"; 
private static final int PORT = 2863;    
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(HOST, PORT); 

  try { 
      jedis.set("foo", "bar"); 
      jedis.get("foo"); 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
      System.err.println("Unable to connect to Redis"); 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
```

When i test redis server with jedis client,  i got the following 
exception.

```
 redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: 
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out 
         at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:124) 
         at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:  54) 
         at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:  77) 
         at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.set(BinaryClient.java:71) 
         at redis.clients.jedis.Client.set(Client.java:21) 
         at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.set(Jedis.java:48)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you: telnet 50.30.35.9 2863 ?

Comment: I am unable to reach the Redis instance hosted by Redis4you even via 
telnet, even though the Redis4you portal claims it is running. How do 
I debug the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The question is:

- *Why you are getting a [SocketTimeoutException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)*

#### The answer is:

Because you cannot connect to the host and port you have in your code, since you cannot `telnet 50.30.35.9 2863` to it.

#### The follow up question is:

- *I am unable to reach the Redis instance hosted by Redis4you even via telnet, even though the Redis4you portal claims it is running. How do I debug the root cause of this issue?*

#### The answer is:

[Contact](http://redis4you.com/contact.php) Redis4You, and find out. From Redis4You contact page:

=> You can contact us with questions or for support issues at following email: `redis (@) e-nick . org` In case of problems with status of the servers, please follow our Twitter account: `redis4you`. You can also post comments and questions there, but email will be easier and faster way.

---

Also looking at their Twitter feed on October 17th they "*have upgraded the system to newly released Redis 2.4.0. You need to stop and then start your instance so the upgrade to happen for you.*"

Answer (score -1):

if ubuntu：
sudo ufw allow 2863/tcp 
or close your firewall